# Get-Disk returns HealthStatus "Warning" and OperationalStatus "Other" for Compellent iSCSI volume

Tags: powershell, diskmanagement

We utilize Dell Compellent storage and I'm in the process of developing a script to provision new iSCSI volumes to Windows servers using the Dell PowerShell SDK.

I've successfully provisioned a volume to a server using the Cookbook commands (https://downloads.dell.com/solutions/storage-solution-resources/Dell-Storage-PowerShell-SDK-Cookbook-%282095-WP-PS%29.pdf)

I'm now querying the provisioned disks on the server with `get-disk -CimSession $cimsession` and I noticed odd output. The newly provisioned disk is indicating a HealthStatus of Warning and an OperationalStatus of Stressed. I feel like this may be a red herring since I haven't formatted or assigned the disk yet. However, the other disks which are all online and functioning normally indicate the same Warning with an operational status of "Other".

I took a look at the MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830493(v=vs.85).aspx) and it indicates

> Other, 1, A vendor-specific OperationalStatus has been specified by setting the OtherOperationalStatusDescription property.

This is not terribly helpful as *OtherOperationalStatusDescription* isn't actually a property of the MSFT_Disk object but instead for MSFT_StorageSubSystem class and I have no idea how to query that info. I've tried various ways to call that and the GetDiagnosticInfo method it contains but no dice.

I tried googling for "Stressed" and "Other" along with various dell, disk, get-disk, and keywords but I'm not coming back with anything providing any reasons or suggestions on these statuses.

**EDIT 1:** Tried the following suggestions but didn't get what I need:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_VirtualDisk -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage"
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_TargetPort -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage"
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_StorageSubSystem -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage"
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_StoragePool -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage"
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_FileServer -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage"

Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_VirtualDisk -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\Providers_v2"
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_TargetPort -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\Providers_v2"
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_StorageSubSystem -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\Providers_v2"
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_StoragePool -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\Providers_v2"
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_FileServer -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\Providers_v2"

Get-WmiObject -Class SPACES_StoragePool -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\Providers_v2"
Get-WmiObject -Class SPACES_StorageSubSystem -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\Providers_v2"
Get-WmiObject -Class SPACES_VirtualDisk -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\Providers_v2"
Get-WmiObject -Class WSP_FileServer -Namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\Providers_v2"
```

Some of these return objects with *OtherOperationalStatusDescription* but the value is blank. None of the objects seem to be for a specific disk however. MSFT_StorageSubSystem returned a "Storage Spaces" object which seems to abstract the disk statuses into an overall status of "Healthy".

Comment: `$namespace = "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage"` or `"ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage\Providers_v2"` and `$classname = "MSFT_VirtualDisk"` or `"MSFT_TargetPort"` or `"MSFT_StorageSubSystem"` or `"MSFT_StoragePool"` or `"MSFT_FileServer"`. In the latter namespace, try also classes `SPACES_StoragePool`, `SPACES_StorageSubSystem`, `SPACES_VirtualDisk`, `WSP_FileServer`. Something like `Get-WmiObject -Class $classname -Namespace $namespace`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but none of those yielded results. The ones that did contain OtherOperationalStatusDescription were objects representing all disks and the status was blank. I think I need to somehow specifically pull that status for specific disk but it doesn't make sense since the disk objects don't contain the property.